# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly System.Xml.Linq

Tags: c#, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mono

I have a mono project that runs fine on my computer (running Ubuntu 16.04), but when I upload it on Ubuntu in AWS, it throws this exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Amazon.AWSConfigs' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

On the Ubuntu server, I've installed mono using `sudo apt-get install mono-runtime`. I assume this didn't install the DLL for System.Xml.Linq.

Note the error isn't about the assembly reference, it's about the actual assembly DLL file missing. Using `strace mono ParamStoreTest.exe` shows that it tries to search for the DLL but can't find it:

```
open("/usr/lib/System.Xml.Linq.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running `dpkg -S System.Xml.Linq` to find out which package installs it, I ran `sudo apt-get install libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil` on the EC2 machine. This fixed the issue.